# Wordpress - Count per Day

Tags: php, wordpress

When I activate Count-Per-Day plugin in administration panel showing me this error, but not on the site.

```
Warning: session_start(): open(/tmp/sess_c8f005a6152407d7c72930471b314416, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/portal/public_html/wp-content/plugins/count-per-day/counter-core.php on line 190

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/portal/public_html/wp-content/plugins/count-per-day/counter-core.php:190) in /home/balkanli/public_html/wp-content/plugins/count-per-day/counter-core.php on line 190
```

Does anyone know why this shows me?
And how can this be solved?